# Print emulation in IE through inspect element

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Is there any way I can do print emulation in IE. In Chrome and Firefox it works great but I need specifically for IE.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to print to PDF each time.  Personally, I would tweak the site using the Chrome and Firefox tools, then print it to PDF in IE to see if any final tweaks need to be made.